# Is there a way I can show nearby points of interest on a Map in Website (pHp) / Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, google-maps

I am new to StackOverflow and in the field of coding (mostly self taught).

I have been trying to get around a slight functionality requirement:
I am working on a Wordpress website utilizing maps. I already have my Google Maps API (Javascript, Places, Geocoding) setup.

I want to show a map on my website, which picks-up current location of the user and displays emergency points around it such a ATMs, Police Stations, Hospitals etc in a 10-30 km radius. I am relying on the Google Maps data itself showing up on that map.

Is there any insight/help/guidance that I can get from the SO community on how to actively achieve this? Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: do you have a DB of locations with latitude and longitude?

Comment: You can refer to the following link, https://en.support.wordpress.com/google-maps/

Comment: Hi @delboy1978uk. I do not have a database as you mention. I was kind of hoping to pull the map info from Google places but not sure if that can happen. I think we have DBs available online for same.

Comment: Sure Shahid. I will go through the document you shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in a *JavaScript code* using **Google Maps Platform Maps JavaScript API** together with the **HTML5 Geolocation feature** and **Google Maps Places Library's Nearby Search Requests**.

Here is a [sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/u3pfjky4/) I made to help you on this use case. Here is also a breakdown of the code:

1. Get the **user location** and **pin** it on the center of the map

Use the [Geolocation code example](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation) to achieve this. Here it is in the code:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };


            map.setCenter(pos);
            //Put marker of the Geolocated user location
            var userMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: pos
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(userMarker, 'click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent('Your location');
                infoWindow.open(map, this);
            });
```

2. Use [Places Library's Nearby Search](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) request to get the nearby place type you want. Since Nearbysearch has only **one** type to be specified in the requests, you need to create 3 requests variables like this:

```
            var requestHosp = {
                location: pos,
                radius: '10000',
                type: ['hospital']
            };
            var requestAtm = {
                location: pos,
                radius: '10000',
                type: ['atm']
            };
            var requestPolice = {
                location: pos,
                radius: '10000',
                type: ['police']
            };
```

Then make Places NearbySearch requests like this:

```
            var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.nearbySearch(requestHosp, callback);
            service.nearbySearch(requestAtm, callback);
            service.nearbySearch(requestPolice, callback);
```

Notice that it is calling a *callback function*. This function creates a **marker** for every place returned. This function should look like this:

```
function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var place = results[i];
            createMarker(results[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

For the *createMarker function*, first you need to *check for the specific place type* on the place types array to determine the icon you will use in your place. It should look like this:

```
 var type = place.types;
    var iconStyle;
    //loop to all the type of the place
    for (var i = 0; i < type.length; i++) {
        //put array of Place types in placeType variable
        var placeType = type[i];        
        //Check the placeType and set the icon according to the placeType value
        switch (placeType) {
            case "hospital":
                iconStyle = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/pharmacy_rx.png"
                break;
            case "atm":
                iconStyle = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/dollar.png";
                break;
            case "police":
                iconStyle = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/police.png"
                break;
        }
    }

//put marker of the places in the map
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: iconStyle,
        position: place.geometry.location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(place.name);
        infoWindow.open(map, this);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed guidelines. You rock!

Comment: Hi Pagemag, I tried it out and it is brilliant. Have been able to add one more filter parameter to it myself :) . Do you have any suggestions on how I can possibly add this code  on a WordPress website?